# How to get current language code in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I try to develope a new application with CakePHP, and in my html tag I have the property lang that support a language iso code in that form en-us

How can I retrive from CakePHP that code for the current selected language;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP processes before HTML, you can't. I would suggest using CakePHP to set the language (since it will be handling the translations anyway), then outputting that on your `<html>` tag.